# How to version control a directory with only binary files?

Tags: git, file, svn, version-control, binaryfiles

I know git/svn etc. can be used for code repos.

I want version control for a directory full of dll files. This will give me a way to go back in time when the directory gets screwed by constant updates from 3rd party programs.

The solution should be space-efficient, something better than zip-back-up of the directory.

Let me add some more context:

Using svn can solve the problem but I am looking for something light-weight and specialized for this job, which I can distribute with my software installer. I can't expect svn/git available at every deployment site.

Comment: If you already know how to use git, you can use it directly. Git doesn't really care what kind of files you throw in there, though its ability to intelligently calculate diffs and do merges won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion is a universal version-control system and it was designed to handle **both** textual and binary data.

Generally speaking, Subversion repository does not care whether the versioned file is human-readable or not — SVN's diff engine is a binary delta algorithm (xdelta), not a contextual diff engine. Subversion’s xdelta compression algorithm works both for textual content and non-compressed binary data. If you change several bytes in a non-compressed multi-gigabyte binary file, Subversion needs only to store those bytes (plus metadata) for the new version of your file.